# How Push Notifications Sent?

Tags: android, push-notification

I just want to understand how the push Notifications will be sent to users? I aware of Parse, Urban Airship to implement this functionality.

My Doubt is how the news apps or some other feed apps will send Push Notification?

Will some person who is responsible for the app sends notifications  every day by going to parse dash board or Urban airship dashboard edit and sends message?

will they schedule the messages in advance or will they use scheduler(Timers or Alarms) in apps like every day at particular time they should read the message from server and show notifications?

I want to develop an App where the user should get a message every day. I just want to know like how these Notifications work.

Appreciate your suggestions . Thank you.

Comment: what is this "message" going to contain? If its just a notification about some news article or something you would be better off setting an alarm and pinging the server every day vs having the server have a bunch of timers to send a push to each device that may or may not even be on or even installed anymore

Comment: Thank you . will parse and urban airship allows server side coding to schedule or scheduler in dash board is the option? Because i tried alarm Manager in client side for android. But its not working as expected with interval of a day. here is my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828403/setinexactrepeating-in-alarm-manager-is-not-working-as-expected